# alguien me podría auxiliar como hacer mas rápida la conexión a la base de datos desde Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle

Resulta que la consulta tarda como 30 seg. y cuando se corre la aplicación tarda en cargar una tabla con los registros entre 1 min y min y medio, la consulta aunque esta con un SP ya no puede ser mas optimizada, sin embargo debe de haber algo que acelere la conexión desde el Visual Studio. Trabajo con c# asp en tres capas. Gracias

Comment: Cuánto tiempo se tarda si ejecutas directamente el `stored procedure` en oracle? Cuántos registros devuelve esa consulta?

Comment: @Bicho si ejecuto directamente el SP se tarda 30 seg.

Comment: Falta muchísima información. Estás utilizando Entity Framework? Qué versión? Estás utilizando MySQLClient? No has mostrado la capa de acceso a datos.

Comment: Falta más información: que hace el procedimiento? que parámetros de entrada se pasán? cuáles son de salida? hay manera que publique que hace el procedimiento? ¿Cuál es la consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas bueno estos son algunos consejos que te puedo brindar y si estas trabajando en localhost:

1. Usa storedprocedures al no ejecutar código nativo SQL puedes optimizar tiempo.
2. No traigas todos tus registros de golpe puedes usar tus registros por partes como la
   paginación **(Listar los 30 primeros items).**
3. El modelo de tu base de datos también importa es recomendable usar index para que
   puedas extraer información en menor tiempo .
4. Prueba con cambiar de Oracle a SQL SERVER debido a que .NET esta mejor optimizado en
   SQL SERVER.

Comment: A qué te refieres con *mejor optimizado*?

Comment: Por qué cambiar a sql server? Si el proyecto ya está en producción con oracle? Si es un requerimiento del cliente utilizar oracle?

Comment: @gustavo sanchez gracias por tus recomendaciones, lamentablemente es un proyecto al que ya se ha trabajado por años y ahora que me toco colaborar ya tiene  mucha informacion en produccion, por eso no puedo usar index a la BD ni editarla tan facilmente asi como es requisito usar a fuerza Oracle.

Comment: @Bicho, si es un requerimiento del cliente trabajar con Oracle lamentablemente o esta en mi poder cambiar a SQL Server